# Como almacenar varios Dataframe (con resultado en SQL) en uno solo en python

Tags: python, oracle, dataframe

recorro un archivo y por cada registro hago una consulta en oracle a través de python, cada consulta trae una cantidad x de registros, actualmente, guardo el resultado de la consulta en un dataframe, pero solo me deja almacenado en el dataframe el resultado de la última consulta, yo requiero que cada consulta se vaya almacenando en el MISMO dataframe consolidado.

```
for i, row in archivo.iterrows():
    
  pagina=archivo.loc [i,'PAGINA']

  Subcadenapagina = pagina[:-6]

  sql = "SELECT * from clientes where PAGINA LIKE '"+Subcadenapagina+"%' "
```

## aca ejecuto la consulta y la almaceno en un DF pero cuando el for continua, borra el DF y sobreescribe con los resultados de la nueva consulta, requiero que los registros totales salgan en un DF único consolidado.

```
  df=pd.read_sql(sql,conexion_aplicacion)
```

Comment: agrega los resultados a un dataframe que ya tengas, lo puedes hacer con `.concat` o `.append()`

Comment: lo había intentado previamente agregando esta línea: df_concatenado.append(df) pero me almacena el último dataframe, igualmente pasa con el concat, sucede que normalmente uno anexa todos los dataframe al tiempo pero al ir ingresando de a uno, parece que solo almacena el último (puede ser que estoy omitiendo algo en la sintaxis)

Answer (score 2):

Muchas gracias Christian, era como tu decías pero me faltaba manejar bien la variable result

```
df=pd.read_sql(sql,conexion_hidro)
result=pd.concat([result,df])
```